# Visual Studio Code - Auto insert next line bracket on enter formatting

Tags: format, visual-studio-code, curly-braces

I recently switch to vscode, but what I liked about studio is when you type ( | = cursor):

```
if (true){|
```

it auto-formats it to:

```
if (true){|}
```

AND THEN if you hit enter it would format:

```
if (true)
{
    |
}
```

in vscode you have to arrow back and hit enter, then tab in to do this same thing. Anyone know what settings or extensions I need to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: use the `if` snippet or write your own version. But what is the use of the `{` on an otherwise empty line? Or use one of the formatters.

Comment: Just used to my code looking that way developing in Unity. Been digging through formatters but can't seem to find what I am looking for. Thanks for mentioning snippets I will take a look at that